# Add exception for wrong certificate for subdomain "ssl_error_bad_cert_domain"

Tags: firefox, certificates, https, tls

One of my domains I use has an HTTPS certificate that is only valid for `example.com`. Whenever I try to access one of the subdomains I get an error:

```
The website uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)
```

and `Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain`.

I know I should reconfigure my webserver, but since we only use these domains internally, I would rather just be able to add an exception.

This is not possible any more (tested in Firefox 37 on Ubuntu 14.10)

How can I add an exception?

Comment: Did you have a working (trusted) certificate on the **subdomains** before? Because HSTS works on a domain basis and only for trusted connections, you must have had a secure trusted connection with HSTS enabled in order to get to this error now. If you were indeed in this situation, I could provide an answer to flush the HSTS cache in your browser and to disable HSTS for your subdomains now that they are untrusted. For the latter part, please provide your current web server configuration.

Comment: https://freifunk.in-kiel.de/

Answer (score 2):

In private browsing mode, you can still add a temporary exception.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open a private window.